# Chirality and Colored Jones Polynomial

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory, knot-invariants

It is well understood that the usual Jones polynomial of a knot or link can be related to the Jones polynomial of the mirror image of the knot/link by changing the variable $V_L(t) \to V_L(t^{-1})$. More generally, the HOMFLY-PT polynomial of the mirror image can be obtained by switching from $P_L(l,m) \to P_L(l^{-1},m)$.

So can an equivalent statement be made about the Coloured Jones Polynomial of an arbitrary link, for the same colouring? For a link $L$ and mirror image $L^*$ is the relation $C^{L}_{N,M,\cdots}(t) = C^{L^*}_{N,M,\cdots}(t^{-1})$ true? Is there a reference for this?

The Borromean and Hopf link are supposedly achiral, and switching to the inverse given the equations for CJP keeps it unchanged. But then there is this [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271523/1-s2.0-S0166864100X02362/1-s2.0-S0166864101000621/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjECMaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDBxa1ZMv%2F4ti7V6NTMRg99X%2BGQCNBGLjYNU%2BeoF%2Fc%2FSQIgTwODeroanA5uuD84hIyYYbBkEfEwCpHyaLZ1eB%2FUsh8qvAUI%2B%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDAC4a5vT3pRGWcdMLSqQBaEuoYLSIc%2Feg6s2Alygf4OmEiIxHo5VCdPQlTgAk7W2psixbD%2BpxzV53ZqA%2FZWzIrD%2FlVjJ9nNGg8hJydoAghpbwKGH1orpuHY%2BPb9%2BLBZzqAMmWsriYKYIYW%2F5K48x%2BPuJ0JLLBBhZFVJDsQdVfjQLwQ1geCjW%2B8Effn8TzQKatGJJa3x20TalszlhkXKoZOsQMhlo1FmGydtwWbKIEk6S7Z4Z%2FOgFf1%2BgpxB3Y6zgv6LKTWZhVVO1jJwUwRk95I%2B5QsQYR8UhGNJ%2BrjGj6MpLS8NEeM6ea8A%2FaZyoEedUylutJQEuxMYiyZqvFiN7pS2HIixNnjTS4RcpiM4LtKz%2B3%2FVVPsOGz3xK5KXAROw1n5ndwFKc6FZL7luIfpk51mVrpzr%2BsDKGTLjh725YW6mg4jy9sI9Si11s3%2F%2B9PLstJZ6515n7LWVufsqs1YCmWSIqaAYe2gqUWQ59WANW8PYm6F6iQzGqgkc5JYbPNZnXbwQfOIvpOyfBDPPqgSf%2B5vn%2FDBOIfVCt1dJqr5GrRtNjg9c0A%2BLECf0X9fD57EB7ktLTcZoV8Fr9oWGAtAbF2YCFM%2FgsNbm1jZhy3WE2zLhSJqPyREcJ0q4P7Mpq%2BgtTDMwAptdoCiWWkyMUKKy0gcLewiax8JE0HNfKy5URlFv2VakFNrEuKlPkN%2B1MtSjk4Mkvwn2ag5Fhks8rpsRxPT2aAOdxpiQBikpCLPMkb9lipzmL2HgFH0RlzxVKtKspPgc9ZAAKUHEQ%2BDWpfd%2BJdG6L7eBh4TjP8air%2FiZFYwrGL4dayxJzBopDx3QxN8lLwfFNJaT16m7F7m%2FIC4vOJWKEzr1rBy6SZmpMUdDzJ1%2BE3wLrjb%2FEtF0OlXytSwZkMLPxyq4GOrEBfB0SgL%2FYUGwmIQDSE50iIxJGWHD8yTU0XoYzGmBAQF9QMJLIfGsPyt1DQWEFJuGTv2yMKLYvKwd2fCSUcnSuidd8f%2FYwC%2BxiTZoWiRXeWAbuy%2BEEYCp07goHUNIyJOmPLDMR5aW6CV3PdBe4RT1qTXBo7sq3UCLkgUYOt8SIWlW21FO97oS22kK%2F8u9Gzx46Hdq0dugYP7FkJdUjof5gURaOg08EBOtMwKILxhiqkBFw&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240219T024646Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY45BSNB4W%2F20240219%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=90e20ce23df85ff7a83024337d2f95d78accd6ca3e6018b476bd6e03221de607&hash=46a7dc33ab26d7d1be15da8a73dea960942f6bf2260ef4fb6d69b1474fa78090&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0166864101000621&tid=spdf-c9feda60-cd8f-4f87-8d27-0d47e88fc375&sid=2436da0d3f9c884d711aeb19905282a439cfgxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=0a0e5b5157005705575c&rr=857b2e682d2b3527&cc=pl) where it seems that this should only be the case for the Borromean link, not the Hopf link, so something seems to be going wrong

Comment: Could you explain which result of the paper you mention, would imply that it would not hold for the Hopf link?

Comment: @MPos Theorem 4.8. All non-trivial prime links L with at least two components and at most 9 crossings are positive and negative chiral, except the Borromean rings.

Comment: I looked briefly through the paper and I think the confusion is due to the following terminology: For an oriented link $L$, they call the link positively achiral if there the mirror image $L^\ast$ is isotopic to $L$ preserving the orientations and positively achiral otherwise. Similarly they define negatively (a)chiral in the setting where all orientations in the mirror get reversed. In this terminology, the Hopf link as an oriented link is both positively and negatively chiral, it is really $(1,-1)$-achiral. So neither $(1,1)$- or $(-1,-1)$-achiral.

Comment: However, it is achiral as an unoriented link! Note also that the Jones polynomial (even the colored one) does not care about orientation. In particular, the Jones polynomial does not detect this notion of $\epsilon$-(a)chirality.